# Visible elements in the pipeline editor

Tags: localhost, streampipes

I am new to figuring out how stream pipes work. I have been trying to download the repositories from [GitHub](https://github.com/streampipes).

When I open local host, I get a set of elements in the [pipeline editor](https://github.com/streampipes/streampipes-ce). What are these elements dependent on? How can I know what elements to expect in the pipeline editor?

Comment: What is this pipeline editor and which github project are you dealing with?

Comment: The [pipeline editor](https://www.streampipes.org/en/open_source) is a graphical, web-based editor to easily create processing pipelines. The GitHub project is [here](https://github.com/streampipes).

Answer (score 1):

In StreamPipes, pipeline elements are **standalone components** (you can think of microservices that contain the processing logic of a data processor or data sink). Pipeline elements encapsulate their dependencies and rely on one of several available [runtime wrappers](https://docs.streampipes.org/docs/dev-guide-architecture) (e.g., in an Apache Flink cluster or as single-host JVM wrappers).

The pipeline elements that are installed by default can be found on [Github](https://www.github.com/streampipes/streampipes-pipeline-elements). The README file contains a short description of each pipeline element.

You can also use the built-in **SDK** to build your own pipeline elements, see the [tutorial](https://docs.streampipes.org/docs/dev-guide-tutorial-processors) for a quick walkthrough.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi maybe you can also answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64875063/mailing-list-slack-group-js-module-for-streampipes